# get selected/highlighted text html in gmail compose mail area

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am designing an chrome extension for Gmail. In this I want to get selected/highlighted text. I tried following code:

```
    if (!window.x) {
        x = {};
    }

    x.Selector = {};
    x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
        var t = '';
        if($('.compose-container').getSelection){
            t = $('.compose-container').getSelection();
            alert(t);
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            t = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.getSelection) {
            t = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            t = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

It is not giving me selected text in compose mail.
Please help me out.

Comment: Might need to use rangy https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per gRenzFries answer, I code same as link provided by him. But slight addition in code to paste it in textbox.

Code to Copy text :

```
var emailLink = document.querySelector('.gmail_default');  
var range = document.createRange();  
range.selectNode(emailLink);  
window.getSelection().addRange(range);  

try {  
    // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command  
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy', true);  
} catch(err) {
}
```

Code to paste it in textbox:

```
$('#text-to-display').val("");    //reset textbox value
$('#text-to-display').focus();    //set focus to textbox
document.execCommand("Paste");
```

This code works just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the copy command to achieve this.

```
var copyText = document.execCommand('copy');
```

Basically it will copy any text selection in the browser.

You can check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands) on how it was fully utilized

Comment: Hey thanks. It only copies data to clipboard but I want to show selected text in textbox as well. If I use Ctrl + v command I am getting copied text but I want to do it without  Ctrl + v click. Is it possible?