# Using Google Extensions to Copy and Paste into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-extension

I am in the process of creating a Chrome Extension that copies text from one page. I would like to post the content to Text view in Wood Press, which has the following HTML:

```
<div id="content-textarea-clone" class="wp-exclude-emoji" style="font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19.5px; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; width: 517px;">Test&amp;nbsp;</div>
```

I attempt to update the content of this div using:

```
var art = document.getElementById("content-textarea-clone")
art.innerHTML = '<p>blah blah</p><p>blah blah blah</p>
```

Whatever I try it does not work. It is like the content is being reset.My guess is that there is some javascript in this page that is resetting this content somehow. Is there a way for me to update the content of the element content-textarea-clone without it resetting?

Comment: What is the relationship between the DOM and rendered page?

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow related to [get selected/highlighted text html in gmail compose mail area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525135/get-selected-highlighted-text-html-in-gmail-compose-mail-area/34544440#34544440). As answered, you will need the copy command:

```
var copyText = document.execCommand('copy');
```

And to paste:

```
$('#text-to-display').val(""); //reset textbox value
$('#text-to-display').focus(); //set focus to textbox
document.execCommand("Paste");
```

Please note also, when using most Chrome APIs, your extension or app must declare its intent in the "permissions" field of the `manifest`. Each permission can be either one of the list of known strings such as "clipboardWrite" which is required for hosted apps and is recommended for extensions and packaged apps as discussed in [Declare Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).